# Apollo nodejs server; How to get mutation/query schema path in the request context when writing a plugin?

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

I'm writing an Apollo server plugin for node.js, and my goal is to improve my teams debugging experience. My plugin currently looks something like this:

```js
export function eddyApolloPlugin(): ApolloServerPlugin {
    return {
        requestDidStart(requestContext) {
            // Set requestId on the header
            const requestId = (requestContext?.context as EddyContext)?.requestId;
            if (requestId) {
                requestContext.response?.http?.headers.set('requestId', requestId);
            }
            return {
                willSendResponse(context) { // <== Where do I find the "path" in the schema here?
                    // Inspired by this: https://blog.sentry.io/2020/07/22/handling-graphql-errors-using-sentry
                    // and the official documentation here: https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/node/
                    // handle all errors
                    for (const error of requestContext?.errors || []) {
                        handleError(error, context);
                    }
                },
            };
        },
    };
}
```

I would like to know if I can access the path in the schema here? It's pretty easy to find the name of mutaiton/query with `operation.operationName`, but where can I get the name of the query/mutation as defined in the schema?

**Solution**

```js
export function eddyApolloPlugin(): ApolloServerPlugin {
    return {
        requestDidStart(requestContext) {
            // Set requestId on the header
            const requestId = (requestContext?.context as EddyContext)?.requestId;
            if (requestId) {
                requestContext.response?.http?.headers.set('requestId', requestId);
            }
            return {
                didResolveOperation(context) {
                    const operationDefinition = context.document
                        .definitions[0] as OperationDefinitionNode;
                    const fieldNode = operationDefinition?.selectionSet
                        .selections[0] as FieldNode;
                    const queryName = fieldNode?.name?.value;
                    // queryName is what I was looking for!
                },
            };
        },
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your requirement is not very clear. If you want to get the name of the query/mutation to distinguish which query or mutation the client sends.

You could get the name from `context.response.data` in `willSendResponse` event handler.

E.g.

`server.ts`:

```js
import { ApolloServer, gql } from 'apollo-server';
import { ApolloServerPlugin } from 'apollo-server-plugin-base';
import { parse, OperationDefinitionNode, FieldNode } from 'graphql';

function eddyApolloPlugin(): ApolloServerPlugin {
  return {
    requestDidStart(requestContext) {
      return {
        didResolveOperation(context) {
          console.log('didResolveOperation');
          const obj = parse(context.request.query!);
          const operationDefinition = obj.definitions[0] as OperationDefinitionNode;
          const selection = operationDefinition.selectionSet.selections[0] as FieldNode;
          console.log('operationName: ', context.request.operationName);
          console.log(`${context.operation!.operation} name:`, selection.name.value);
        },
        willSendResponse(context) {
          console.log('willSendResponse');
          console.log('operationName: ', context.request.operationName);
          console.log(`${context.operation!.operation} name:`, Object.keys(context.response.data!)[0]);
        },
      };
    },
  };
}

const typeDefs = gql`
  type Query {
    hello: String
  }
  type Mutation {
    update: String
  }
`;
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    hello() {
      return 'Hello, World!';
    },
  },
  Mutation: {
    update() {
      return 'success';
    },
  },
};

const server = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers, plugins: [eddyApolloPlugin()] });
const port = 3000;
server.listen(port).then(({ url }) => console.log(`Server is ready at ${url}`));
```

GraphQL Query:

```
query test {
  hello
}
```

the logs of the server:

```
didResolveOperation
operationName:  test
query name: hello
willSendResponse
operationName:  test
query name: hello
```

GraphQL Mutation:

```
mutation test {
  update
}
```

the logs of the server:

```
didResolveOperation
operationName:  test
mutation name: update
willSendResponse
operationName:  test
mutation name: update
```

Comment: I think you understand my question - sorry if it was unclear. Will just test the solution - 2 minutes :)

Comment: Ohh wait - I was a bit fast on the trigger there. What I'm interested is the query name from your above example. But I would like to get this before the resolver is called. Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: According to the docs I can get the operationName from `didResolveOperation` --> but how do I get the queryName ?

Comment: @DauleDK Wait, Let me check.

Comment: Since the query is there as a string, it would maybe be possible to extract the queryName with a regex? Just needs to check for both named and un-named queries

Comment: @DauleDK Updated answer. Get the query/mutation name from the AST node. We convert string query document into `DocumentNode`(AST) using `parse` function.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer - will look into it when I get back to the computer!

Comment: Turns out that parsing is not needed, since the `didResolveOperation` hook already has the query parsed as `context.document`. Updating my question with the solution - thanks for the help!